# Yii2: how to pass image url as array in blueimp Gallery

Tags: php, yii, yii2

```
<!-- Carousel -->
<?php
foreach ($todo as $key => $row) {
foreach (explode(';', rtrim($row['images'], ';')) as $key_img => $value_img) {
$items[] = ['url' => $value_img, 'src' => $value_img];
}
}
?>
<div class="products_inside_wrapper intro_wrapper">
<div class="classes_inside_item bordered_wht_border">
<?php echo dosamigos\gallery\Gallery::widget(['items' => $items]); ?>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Carousel End -->
```

Using 2amigos gallary widget, Im not getting images. please let me know what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I just reformatted for a my better reading (missing a ;)

```
<!-- Carousel -->
<div class="products_inside_wrapper intro_wrapper">
<div class="classes_inside_item bordered_wht_border">                                        
<?php 
    foreach ($todo as $key=>$row){
        foreach (explode(';',rtrim($row['images'],';')) as $key_img => $value_img) {
            $items[] = ['url' => $value_img, 'src' => $value_img];

        }
    }
?>                                            
</div>
<?php echo dosamigos\gallery\Gallery::widget(['items' => $items]); ?>
</div>
<!-- Carousel End -->
```

and be sure you have proper value in $value_img (try a var_dump)

and i think you need also a

```
 src' => 'yuor_path_for_src_image'
```

proper value

In bluimp doc I have found

```
<?php $items = [
[
    'url' => 'http://farm8.static.flickr.com/7429/9478294690_51ae7eb6c9_b.jpg',
    'src' => 'http://farm8.static.flickr.com/7429/9478294690_51ae7eb6c9_s.jpg',
    'options' => array('title' => 'Camposanto monumentale (inside)')
],
```

where you can see value for `url` and for `src` the in many case these are separate path for fullimage and small image .. .

Comment: result of var_dump `string(24) "uploads/room_img/bb8.jpg"`  getting only one image not all three..

Comment: by adding `src=>` getting all the images on same page :P

Comment: I mean you should complete the bluimp gallery with proper src value for each image ..

Comment: if i need to specify image path for src then there is no point for using foreach loop it should take full path automatically for each image in database

Comment: because i have saved image path in database

Comment: You can't extract the name from one and the calculate the second?

Comment: i really dont know how to do that please help

Comment: path saved in db is like `uploads/room_img/bb6.jpg;uploads/room_img/bb7.jpg;uploads/room_img/bb8.jpg;`

Comment: I have update the asnwer with a brief explanation ...anyway the paths in comment above are the path of the image only? .. you don't have small miniature image?

Comment: no i dont have small miniature image, what im asking is instead of writing `[
    'url' => ''1.jpg"
    'src' => ''1.jpg",
],` for every image what if i write only once and it should work for all the images

Comment: You should use [ 'url' => ''1.jpg", 'src' => ''1.jpg", ] .. i have update the answer .. i hope is useful..

Comment: `$items[] = ['url' => $value_img, 'src' => $value_img]; ` this is not working  scaisEdge :)

Comment: actually all images are getting stacked on each other,im getting all images at one page only its not working Carousel I think widget is taking all images as one parameter.

Comment: You need a sort of pagination?  ... have you  checked  if the widget have this feature .. otherwise you should  split  the set of images for manage their show on several pages ..